# Magento 2: Change only one static file

Tags: magento-2.1, static-content

Sometimes I only need to change one static file, is it possible to do that?

Example I have changes to: `/static/versionxxxxxxxx/frontend/Superlove/custom/da_DK/Magento_PageCache/js/page-cache.js`

Can I just manually change it and do System > Cache Management > `Flush JavaScript/CSS` in the admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In Magento2 every static file (served from pub/static folder) is generated by `setup:static-content:deploy` method in `bin/magento` script (or generated on the fly in `developer` mode). This file usually is a link to a file inside module skin folder but I noticed it is not always the case, sometimes the file is copied. In both cases the change done to the file might get reverted. In the first case if module is kept in vendor folder and is reinstalled by `composer install` action or in second when `setup:static-content:deploy` is called another time. If you want to make changes to file from a module you can do this in 2 ways:

1)  copy the file to the theme folder and make changes there. It will be available only in that theme. In you example, assuming you have magento installed via composer packages, copy filde `vendor/magento/module-page-cache/view/frontend/web/js/page-cache.js` to `app/design/frontend/Superlove/custom/Magento_PageCache/js/page-cache.js` and edit file in `app/design` folder. If you have magento installed in `app/code` then the path should be `app/code/Magento/Page_Cache/view/frontend/web/js/page-cache.js`

2) In a custom module create file `view/frontend/web/requirejs-config.js` with similar content

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            pageCache:  'Custom_Module/js/page-cache'
        }
    }
};
```

and in `view/frontend/web/js/page-cache.js` create the file by copying content of original file and modifying it to your needs.